# MySQL Query with Group Header And Details

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grouping

I have 2 Tables like below:

Person

| Name | Age | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AFME | 45 | IT |
| HSAM | 55 | HR |
| MAMK | 35 | Design |

Documents

| Name | DocName | Papers | Fulfilled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HSAM | BirthCe | 1 | True |
| HSAM | ID | 1 | False |
| AFME | BirthCe | 1 | True |
| AFME | ID | 1 | True |

I want to query with the below results

| Name | Age | Department | DocName | Papers | Fulfilled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFME | 45 | IT |  |  |  |
| AFME |  |  | BirthCe | 1 | True |
| AFME |  |  | ID | 1 | True |
| HSAM | 55 | HR |  |  |  |
| HSAM |  |  | BirthCe | 1 | True |
| HSAM |  |  | ID | 1 | False |

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this query is a bit messy.
This should give you what you are expecting:

```
SELECT pName,
pAge,
pDocName,
Papers,
pFulfilled
  FROM (
SELECT 
p.`Name` AS pName
, p.`Age` AS pAge
,'' AS pDocName
,'' AS Papers
,'' AS pFulfilled
, p.`Name` AS sortName
,1 AS sortOrder 
FROM `person` p 
WHERE p.`Name` IN (SELECT d.`Name` FROM `Documents` d)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
''
,''
, d.`DocName`
, d.`Papers`
, d.`Fulfilled`
, d.`Name`,
2 AS sortOrder FROM `Documents` d )a
ORDER BY a.sortName, a.sortOrder, a.pDocName
```

Comment: i tried and succeeded but, when i put any condition in the query it gives unreliable results

Comment: Please be specific, edit your question and tell me where it failed

Answer (score 0):

To get results what you want, you can use the `UNION ALL` operator, which allows you to combine two or more result sets of queries into a single result set. But you must follow:

- First, the number and the orders of columns in all SELECT statements must be the same
- Second, the data types of columns must be the same or compatible

To satisfy both restrictions, you can include `NULL` values ​​for result columns that do not exist in the tables.

So the query would be like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (    
    SELECT
        *,
        NULL AS DocName,
        NULL AS Papers,
        NULL AS Fulfilled
    FROM Person
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Name,
        NULL AS Age,
        NULL AS Department,
        DocName,
        Papers,
        Fulfilled
    FROM Documents
) data
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Documents)
ORDER BY Name
```